# Tokenizing Rule Precedence Pyparsing

Tags: python, tokenize, pyparsing, rule, operator-precedence

Below is my toy parser:

```
from pyparsing import Word,OneOrMore,alphanums,nums

number=Word(nums)
word=OneOrMore(Word(alphanums))
greeting = word+(number)

tests = "Hello3 World 1234"
print tests, "->", greeting.parseString(tests)
```

The results I was expecting to get were

```
['Hello3','World','1234']
```

but instead I get the error:

```
ParseException: Expected W:(0123...) (at char 17), (line:1, col:18)
```

Should not the '1234' string not be matched by the 'number' rule first, and so subsequently be ignored by the 'word' rule?

I suspect it is late at night and I have missed something utterly elementary in the documentation, but I have looked through the 'getting started with pyparsing' O'Reilly pdf twice, and can't find a solution.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: No - '1234' string will be matched by the repetition built into the OneOrMore class, which you have defined to accept one or more words made up of alphanumeric characters, which '1234' matches. If you want word to not accept numbers, then redefine word as `OneOrMore(~number+Word(alphanums))` so that words consisting of all numbers will be included in the word part, so that the following number part will then get a chance at matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is matching your "1234" against the `word` rule since you said it could be alpha or numeric.  The `word` rules keeps capturing the terms including "1234" and so the error is that the `number` rule is never hit.

If you're rule for `word` is closer to python's definition of an identifier (can't start with a digit), this will fix your parser:

```
from pyparsing import Word, OneOrMore, alphas, alphanums, nums

number=Word(nums)
word=OneOrMore(Word(initChars=alphas, bodyChars=alphanums))
greeting = word+(number)

tests = "Hello3 World 1234"
print tests, "->", greeting.parseString(tests)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, your solution solved it. But more generally, why was the 'word' rule applied first and not the 'num'? Was it because the rules are applied left to right, more specific etc.? Is there a way for me to apply the rules in order, without having to change the 'word' rule? In my final application I am hoping to tokenize names, telephone numbers and birth dates in waves, and then apply the grammar to stitch the those pertaining to the same person together. Have I missed the point?

Comment: Yes, `OneOrMore` is greedy and will consume all tokens before the `number` rule is applied.  You'd need to use a `MatchFirst` with `number` ahead of `word` to give precedence.